# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'localename' not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I know this is a repeated question. Sorry for asking. I am having this error in my spring mvc application. 
This is my Impl file

```
public Map<String, String> employeelist() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<Employee> lang1 = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select * from 
     employee", new EmployeeMapper());
    for (int i = 0; i < lang1.size(); i++) {
        map.put(lang1.get(i).getLocalename(), lang1.get(i).getName());
    }
    return map;
}

 public static final class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> {

    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        employee.setSalary(rs.getString("salary"));
        employee.setDesignation(rs.getString("designation"));
        employee.setLocalename(rs.getString("localename"));
        return employee;
    }

}
```

While trying to execute this i am getting an error like `"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'localename' not found"`. All other fields are working correctly. But for **localename** only its showing the error. What is the problem here?? Please help me..

Sorry for my poor english

This is my employee class

```
package com.bct.internal.form.model;

public class Employee {
private String id;
private String name;
private String salary;
private String designation;
private String localename;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(String salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}


public String getLocalename() {
    return localename;
}

public void setLocalename(String localename) {
    this.localename = localename;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [ID=" + id + ", NAME=" + name + ", SALARY=" + salary + 
", LOCALE_NAME=" + localename + ", DESIGNATION=" + designation + "]";
}
}
```

Comment: Does the table `employee` have a column named `localename`? That would obviously be the first thing to check if the error message says that there is no such column.

Comment: @Jesper Yes..it does

Comment: @TanmayDelhikar.. Sure tanmay.. i will edit my question

Comment: Show your Table and its data types?

Comment: But in the code you added the column is named `LOCALE_NAME` with an underscore. You must use that name, not `localename`, in the `rs.getString(...)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

or

```
DESC Employee
```

The column name `localename` is present or not in the table. Also check the datatype of the `localename`.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to your database and execute (be sure to be in the correct schema):

```
DESC employee;
```

You need to be 100% sure that the name of the column 'localename' returned on the table description matches exactly, it should not have underscores or hyphens. This could just be a typo on the table you created.

Answer (score 0):

if the column name `localename` is not present in the table then add the column `localname`, then check column `localname` is mapped or not in hbm file(if using hibernate).